# Use Html Agility Pack to download Bitcoin Price (C#)

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine, html-agility-pack

I need to get bitcoin price from https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/ using Html Agility Pack. I am using this example which works fine:

```
var html = @"http://html-agility-pack.net/";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title");
Console.WriteLine("Node Name: " + node.Name + "\n" + node.OuterHtml);
```

The XPath is: `//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div`

The HTML:

```
<div class="priceValue "><span>$17,162.42</span></div>
```

I have tried code below, but it returns "Object reference not set to an instance of an object":

```
var html = @"https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='priceValue']/span");
Console.WriteLine("Node Name: " + node.Name + "\n" + node.InnerText);`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Side note: It is important to remember that HtmlAgilityPack is **NOT** like a web browser. It does **NOT** execute javascript or wasm. Therefore, it might not be really useful to use a real web browser (like Firefox or Chrome) to inspect the page structure you want to process, as you can't tell whether the page structure you see there in the web browser inspector has been dynamically created/altered by some javascript/wasm script. (In other words, the HTML structure you see in a web browser inspector might not be the actual orignal source html as provided by the web server.)

Comment: While this wouldn't use `HtmlWeb()`, wouldn't a more preferred solution be to use [the API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) provided by the website in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR:

1. You need to tell `HtmlWeb` to decompress the response (or use a proper HTTP client)
2. You need to fix the XPath selector

---

Obviously the `SelectSingleNode()` call returns `null` because it can't find the node.

In cases like this it is helpful to inspect the loaded HTML. You can do this by getting the value of `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml`. I tried this and the "HTML" produced was gibberish.

The reason is that `HtmlWeb` doesn't decompress by default the response it gets. See [this](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues/454) github issue for details. I don't think you would have this problem if you used a proper HTTP client (like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)), or if the HtmlAgilityPack devs were more proactive.

If you insist on using `HtmlWeb`, your code should look like this:

```
const string html = @"https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/";
        
var web = new HtmlWeb
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
};
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(html);

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='priceValue ']/span");
```

Notice that the class for the element you are looking for is actually `priceValue`  (with a space character in the end) and there is another `div` with a class of `priceValue` in the page. This is another issue however and you should eventually be able to find a more robust selector. Maybe something like this:

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'priceSection')]//div[contains(@class, 'priceValue')]/span");
```